# SSRS Time HH:MM:SS Sum

Tags: reporting-services, time, aggregate

Can someone please help me with the following:

I am trying to use an expression to calculate the sum of four different times.

Queue Time, Ring Time, Hold Time, Talk Time

These times are coming from a stored procedure as a single digit (5 seconds is simply value '5')

I have used the following expression to convert this to HH:MM:SS (00:00:05)

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!quetime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction to add these four times together and keep the HH:MM:SS format?

I have tried the following but I get #Error:

```
=Sum(Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!quetime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss") 
+ Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!ringtime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss") 
+ Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!holdtime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
+ Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!TalkTime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss"))
```

(Broken up for on separate lines here for readability)

I would like to do this within SSRS and not in SQL.

Thanks in advance,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I wanted to sum call durations. This is what worked:

1. In SQL I stored HH, MM & SS separately as int. i.e. Column for Hour, Min and Seconds.
2. I used the logic below to sum the values. If a sum value of Mins or Seconds is more than 60 it is converted to the next time scale.
   {=Iif(
   (SUM(Fields!Min.Value) + SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60) >= 60,
   SUM(Fields!Hour.Value) + ROUND((SUM(Fields!Min.Value)+SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60)/60,0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
   SUM(Fields!Hour.Value))
   & " h: "
   & Iif(
   (SUM(Fields!Min.Value) + SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60) < 60,
   ROUND((SUM(Fields!Min.Value)+SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60),0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
   (SUM(Fields!Min.Value) + ROUND(SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60,0,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))-(60 * FLOOR((SUM(Fields!Min.Value)+SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60)/60)))
   & " m: "
   & Iif(
   SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value) < 60,
   SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value),
   SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)-(60 * FLOOR(SUM(Fields!Seconds.Value)/60)))
   & " s"
   }

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

The following did the trick:

```
=Format(DateAdd("s", SUM(Fields!quetime.Value + Fields!ringtime.Value + Fields!holdtime.Value + Fields!TalkTime.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")
```